# What is the better way to test strings for two matches?

Tags: javascript, string, comparison, theory, coding-efficiency

Just out of curiosity:
If I want to test a string for two (or another minor amount of) different words, is it better to use several comparisons or a regex?

```
if (myString == "apple" || myString == "banana")
```

or better

```
if (/apple|banana/.test(myString))
```

I see that a regex will be less code typing, but worse to read. 
What is the (theoretical) technical more efficient method?

(I should not use the "style" tag, so I don't :D)

Comment: I don't know if this question is a good SO question as it will be very opinion-based which way one prefers. Or define 'better' in a concrete way like 'faster', 'uses less memory' etc. Then you get rid of the opinion-part of the question and make it quantifyable ...

Comment: @ufo maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a more suitable forum for this type of question

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Let's say I am interested in the 'faster' solution, so how much actual CPU cycles are needed (or so, I'm not quite into this).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as well

```
var words = {
    apple: true,
    banana: true
};
```

Usage:

```
if (words[myString]) {
```

Or with ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
var words = new Set('apple', 'banana');
```

Usage:

```
if (words.has(myString)) {
```